# Email sender as name not only email address

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I use to send an email notification using:

```
    mail_host = api.portal.get_tool(name='MailHost')
    mail_host.simple_send(
        mto=email, mfrom=mfrom, subject=subject,
        body=mail_text, immediate=True)
```

where

```
     mfrom = 'my_email_address@foo.bar'
```

When an email message is sent I want the `Organization Name` to be displayed instead of email address as I see for other (default) email notifications sent by Plone. How to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mfrom = "Organization Name <my_email_address@foo.bar>"`

I found it here: https://github.com/zopefoundation/Products.MailHost/blob/master/src/Products/MailHost/tests/testMailHost.py#L297

Comment: you can also use
from email import formataddr
api.portal.send_email(sender=formataddr((Name,'email@foo.bar')), ...)